# What type of IC is this? Marking code 6003-001 NQ97P

Tags: identification, bms

Please help me to identfy this IC.

Known information:

- Marking code 6003-001 NQ97P
- Part of the battery of Fimi x8 Mini Drone
- Connected to a [SC8906](https://pese.oss-cn-shenzhen.aliyuncs.com/pdfs/2009090933_Southchip-Semicon-SC8906QFER_C506249.pdf) charger IC

[image]

Comment: what type of a circuit is that?

Comment: What are the package dimensions? Can you show a bit more of the surrounding circuit?

Comment: this package sop 12

Comment: @andikvanroy That looks more like a no lead package type to me: DFN, SON, etc. Anyway, if you don't provide more information (size, surrounding circuit, designator, device it belongs to), I doubt anyone will be able to find the part.

Comment: this ic used in bms battery drone and pairing with SC8906 ,i thing SC8906 use for charging and this ic used for comunication with drone

Comment: I edited this question with the information from your [duplicate post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/681416/help-me-to-find-datasheet-for-this-ic-with-marking-nq97p-i-found-this-ic-in-bms). For the future, please make yourself familiar with how this site works.

Answer (score 5):

It's probably a [Sino Wealth (中颖电子)](https://en.sinowealth.com/homes) SH366003 battery management IC, which seems to be a pin compatible clone of the Texas Instruments BQxxxxx series, like the [BQ28Z620](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq28z620.pdf).

I couldn't find a datasheet, but I've found several clues that lead to this conclusion:

- [This website](http://www.szssyx.com/index.php?m=content&c=index&a=show&catid=15&id=14) sells a [Sino Wealth SH366002](http://www.szssyx.com/uploadfile/2018/0724/20180724041602386.pdf) chip which has a similar package and markings. Note the `6002` marking. The markings are not exactly the same, but the image is a rendering so we can't be sure how accurate it is to the real chip. I couldn't find a photo.

[image]

- The same manufacturer also sells a battery chip with the part number SH36**6003**. This means it would probably be marked `6003`. Sadly there is little public information available and I can't find a datasheet.
- There is a [test report](https://bilder.baur.de/v1/static/a066fad6896906370550ef951694800f) for a "Rechareable Li-ion Polymer Battery". That mentions that the IC is used in the product. The pictures are too low resolution to discern any markings, but it has a (equally low res) schematic that shows the pinout and tells us the package: DFN12-L(4*2.5) which seems consistent with the IC in question.

[image]

- From the picture we get the pinout below. This is identical to some of the TI BQxxxxx series of battery managment ICs which also have the same package (though TI calls it VSON-12). The report calls it an alternative to a Texas Instruments SN28Z719, but I can't find any information about that part outside of the report.

| Number | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | VSS |
| 2 | SRN |
| 3 | SRP |
| 4 | TS1 |
| 5 | SCL |
| 6 | SDA |
| 7 | DSG |
| 8 | PACK |
| 9 | CHG |
| 10 | PBI |
| 11 | VC2 |
| 12 | VC1 |

Comment: okey thank i will tri read write the program to modify battery capacity